# SQL foreign keys with multiple tables

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, html, foreign-key-relationship

If I have three tables:

```
music_genres
-----------
music_type_id
genres
[other unique fields]

minerals
--------
mineral_id
mineral
[other unique fields]

verbs
-----
verb_id
verbs
[other unique fields]
```

and these are populated with:

```
rock
jazz
funk
punk

rock
boulder
stone
shale

rock
wobble
shake
vibrate
```

Now let's say I was displaying a web page for each of these items, each using a separate template, and stored this information in the following table:

```
pages
-----
page_id
page_url
template_url
foreign_key_id
```

with data such as:

```
/page/music-genres/rock/
/music-genres-template.html
1

/page/verbs/rock/
/verb-template.html
1

/page/minerals/rock/
/mineral-template.html
1

/page/minerals/rock/images/
/mineral-images-template.html
1
```

The templates will know that the a foreign key relates to the specific related table, so the mineral template with know to query the minerals table for that table's other fields. However, I don't have any referential integrity. If rock is deleted from the minerals table, I can't use cascading deletes to remove rows from pages, as foreign keys aren't unique. I can think of numerous ways to get around this inelegantly:

- Emulating cascading deletes with
  triggers
- Storing the item type in
  each row of the music_types, minerals
  and verbs tables, and using this a an
  additional foreign key
- Storing the appropriate table name in the pages
  table
- Maintaining the integrity of
  the database with PHP etc.

I'm thinking that there must be a better way of either storing my data or maintaining the integrity of the database. Any thoughts?

Comment: So you have some some that you don't show that generates the primary key that these foreign keys relate to?  So the same key for 'rock' is used in all three tables?

Comment: Exactly. In this case a MySQL autoincrement column. The scenario is obviously hypothetical, but illustrates that I can't rely on another column to be unique across all three tables that can be used to make a compound key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your problem resides here

> The templates will know that the a
>   foreign key relates to the specific 
>   related table,

That's knowledge which is not stored anywhere in the database.

I see two ways out of it:

1. Given that you are actually creating separate tables for each type of 'thing', you should have a differente column for each type of thing referencing the appropriate table in your pages table, setting all columns to null except one (this could be enforced via a constraint)
2. Have a 'master things' table with a unique id which then pages could reference, having both a column to identify the type, and a column pointing to the rest of the unique data, which would be stored in a different table.

Comment: Thanks Vinko. Yes, that's the problem.

1. Potentially a lot of wasted space. Sounds workable for 3 tables, but messy for 30, or even 300!

2. Could you give me an idea of how this could be achieved?

Comment: create table things (id int, type int); create table rocks (id int references things(id) on delete cascade, name varchar, ...); create table pages(id int references things(id) on delete cascade, ...);

Comment: I may be wrong here, because I'm having difficult envisaging this, but that way if I delete a 'thing', it will in turn cascade delete related minerals and pages? That isn't what I'm after. I want to delete a mineral, and in turn delete related things and pages. I can move foreign keys around to allow this, but I can't see how I can make this work with the verbs and music type tables added to the mix.

Comment: No, ignore me, I think I've got it. No rows in minerals, verbs or music types can share an ID because their IDs are generated by things.id? So to insert a new mineral, I'd need to insert a new 'thing', grab the LAST_INSERT_ID, and then insert the extended data into the minerals table with that LAST_INSERT_ID as the primary key?